# A theorem with no body text nevertheless generates a "holder" for the empty body? See below

Tags: beamer, header-footer

%I

```
\documentclass[ aspectratio = 1610 ]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{amsmath}

 \usetheme{Frankfurt} 

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%

  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}%

  {\inserttheoremheadfont\ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\inserttheoremaddition\fi}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}

{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{definition}[ Is it possible to produce this heading without the white bar below?]

\end{definition}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're using the wrong approach. You should call it as `\begin{definition}Text of the definition\end{definition}` and adjust the body to suit your requirements, rather than the header.

Comment: Please, I know what approach I wish to use and the result I wish to obtain.Can you, or can you not, produce the result I requested?